# iOS: How to loop through objects / properties(Non UI elements) of a class object programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nslog, objective-c-runtime

I am trying to `NSLog`, objects/properties of a viewController.

I have worked on looping through subviews,superviews (basically UIElements) like in below code

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController 

{
NSString *string;
NSMutableArray *mutableArray ;
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary;    
}
@property NSString *string;
@property NSMutableArray *mutableArray ;
@property NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary; 


@implementation ViewController

-(void) loopThrough{
  for (id obj in [self.view subviews]) {
    nslog(@"This would print subviews properties%@", obj)
}
```

}

My question is similar to the above is it possible to loop through set of Non UI elements per se NSString, NSArray and etc.,

***`Implementation Scenario`***

I have 4 network call timeout timers in  viewController and when even one is succeeded with network calls, timeout timer has to be disabled. But since there are four network calls happening, I don't want to declare 4 timer global variables of viewController and invalidate each timer separately. Rather I would like to loop through and invalidate timers.

Comment: please be more specific on what you're trying to figure out specifically. You go from one thing to the next

Comment: @user2277872: Edited the Question. hope its clear now.

Comment: Add the timers to an array just like sub-views are added to the array `subviews`. Then you can iterate over that array.

Comment: to use timers for this sound strange for mein the first place. Timeouts should be handled by the classes you use for asynchronous network calls. NSURLSession, NSURLConnection or some 3rd party tools as AFNetworking. once a network call was successful, cancel the others.

Comment: @JefferyThomas: Tried this approach already but felt like a work around in my case. Just like accessing subviews of a view. Was searching for an approach at runtime.

Comment: @vikingosegundo: Using custom activityIndicator and to remove it from view I need to be in view controller. Using a class separately for all network calls along with RestKit. Protocols seemed perfect for this scenario but avoided protocols due to various reasons.

Comment: What reasons could make you fight the framework? I'd say your architecture and design is broken.

Comment: @vikingosegundo: Could you please elaborate on broken ? Having a separate class for network call ? or for not using protocols to implement the same ? I am just trying out the other way implementation to check for retrieving properties (Non UI elements) at runtime and thats the scenario mentioned in the question where its being tried out.

Comment: if you don't use standard and strong patterns for *various reasons* I assume your design is broken for *various reasons*

Comment: Thanks. I agree with you for `various reasons` (mentioned above) on the strong patterns. Would look into it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use Objective C run-time libraries for this

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

- (NSSet *)propertyNames {
   NSMutableSet *propNames = [NSMutableSet set];
   unsigned int outCount, i;
   objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &outCount);
   for (i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {
       objc_property_t property = properties[i];
       NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithCString:property_getName(property) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       [propNames addObject:propertyName];
   }
   free(properties);
   return propNames;
}

- (void)loopThrough {
  for(NSString *key in [self propertyNames]) {
       NSLog (@"value = %@ , property %@",[self valueForKey:key],key);
  }
}
```